# nothing has been written in an input field=>button cant be pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

does somebody knows a script that if nothing has been written in an input field=>button cant be pressed and it will show a message on the screen

C# unity 2d

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `InputField.onValueChanged` method from : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html

Then you check if InputField.Text is empty, then disable the button, else enable it.

To disable button, set `button.interactable = true/false`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [OnValueChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html) which is called after every character changed (added or removed).

On the InputField add

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(InputField))]
public class InputValidator : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Here reference the according Button
    // Via the Inspector or script
    public Button targetButton;

    // As little bonus if you want here reference an info box why the input is invalid
    public GameObject infoBox;

    private InputField inputField;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputField = GetComponent<InputField>();

        // Add callback
        inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(ValidateInput);
    }

    // Additionally validate the input value everytime 
    // The InputField (this component to be exact) gets enabled in the scene
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        ValidateInput(inputField.text);
    }

    private void ValidateInput(string input)
    {
        // Here you could implement some replace or further validation logic
        // if e.g. only certain characters shall be allowed

        // Enable the button only if some valid input is available
        targetButton.interactable = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input);

        // just a bonus if you want to show an info box why input is invalid
        if (infoBox) infoBox.SetActive(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input));
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: it gives me two errors 1/identifer expected 2/invaild expression 'char'

Comment: Updated my answer (it should have been `char` not `Char` as parameter and in the lambda expression `character` instead of `char`). Anyway, I also noticed that `onValidateInput` actually is only called for every char added .. not while removing stuff. As a little bonus I added the option to also show an info box why it's not valid ;)